# How to change label text color in tableview (data stored in an array)

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a tableview that showing data coming from a JSON which stored in array  `var lastDayChange = [String]()`  , and I want to make the label text color red if the result under 0 (like -1 or -2 etc ) and green if the result above the 0 (like 1 or 2 etc); like in the following picture:

[image]

I create this class in the same ViewController.swift file:

```
struct Coin: Codable {
let symbol : String
let price_usd : String
let percent_change_24h : String}
```

and this is my tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BitcoinTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BitcoinTableViewCell

    let lineNumbers = Array(1...200)

    cell.lineNumberLable.text =  " \(lineNumbers[indexPath.row]) -"

    cell.coinNameLable.text = sympolsCoin[indexPath.row]

    cell.priceLable.text = "$" + priceUSDcoin[indexPath.row]

    cell.lastDayChange.text = lastDayChange[indexPath.row] + "%"

    //cell.coinLogoImage.image = UIImage(named : cryptoCurrencyImage[indexPath.row])

    return cell

}
```

And this json with arrays to save data:

```
var coins = [Coin]()

var sympolsCoin = [String]()
var priceUSDcoin = [String]()
var lastDayChange = [String]()



func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data!)

            for info in self.coins {
                self.sympolsCoin.append(info.symbol)
                self.priceUSDcoin.append(info.price_usd)
                self.lastDayChange.append(info.percent_change_24h)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.coinTableView.reloadData()
                }
                //self.coinTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
     }.resume()
}
```

Comment: it is possible to share the project. i will directly implement in your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` this way:

```
cell.lastDayChange.textColor = Float(lastDayChange[indexPath.row])! >= 0 ? .green : .red
```

First, you get the item of `lastDayChange` at the `indexPath` and you cast it from `String` to `Int`, and set the label color based on the value of that item.

Comment: Error : Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to unwrap the casting result.

Comment: Error : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: So your `lastDayChange` array contains strings that can not be casted to `Int`.

Comment: my array only has numbers!

Comment: If you're sure about that check my updated answer please.

Comment: The problem was that we tried to cast floating-point numbers to type `Int`.

Comment: Now it worked! .. and thank you for your new swift 4 if condition answer

Comment: You are welcome ;) This is called ternary operator, and it's not new, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71).

Answer (score 0):

You can change text's color of UILabel's object by this property.

```
cell.priceLable.textColor = .red
```

Comment: kindly read the question, he is asking to change `lastDayChange` colour not `priceLable`colour

Comment: josh grey please read the question carefully then answer. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

In **CellForAt** add following line of code

```
if lastDayChange[indexPath.row] > 0 {
    cell.lastDayChange.textColor = .green
} else {
    cell.lastDayChange.textColor = .red
}
```

Comment: Error : Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String'

Comment: OK So lastDayChange is String.
so you have to convert string to double.
   
 if(Double(lastDayChange[indexPath.row] )> 0){
cell.lastDayChange.textColor = UIColor.green
}else{
cell.lastDayChange.textColor = UIColor.red
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside tableView(_:cellForRowAt:):

```
if(lastDayChange[indexPath.row] >= 0){

 cell.lastDayChange.textColor = UIColor.green
} else {

 cell.lastDayChange.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Hope it's work...